# How can I add Vue.js search filter

Tags: vue.js

I try to learn Vue.js and have now tried to solve a filter search of my array savedMembers. But I can not make it work.

Array name: savedMembers
variables in array, firstName, lastName and email
search field: search

1. How can I add responsive search?
2. How can I update view with saved members?
3. I would like a filter function to filter all values of array. But it´s okey if I only can filter by firstname.

This is my index.html

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <title>Team Page</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <team-page></team-page>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my main.js

```
  template: `
  <div class="team_members">
    <h3>Team</h3>
    <div class="create_member">
      <form action="" @submit.prevent="onSubmit">
        <label for="firstName">First name</label><br>
        <input type="text" v-model="firstName" name="firstName"><br>
        <label for="lasttName">Last name</label><br>
        <input type="text" v-model="lastName" name="lastName"><br>
        <label for="email">Email</label><br>
        <input type="text" v-model="email" name="email"><br>
        <input class="addMemberBtn" type="submit" value="Submit">
      </form>
      <p v-if="errors.length">
        <b>Please correct the following error(s):</b>
        <ul>
          <li v-for="error in errors">{{ error }}</li>
        </ul>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="teamContainer">
      <h3 class="team_header">Team</h3>
      <div class="team_content">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="searchbox">
            <input class="search" type="text" placeholder="Search" v-model="search">
          </div>
          <div class="createMemberBtn">
            <button>Add New Team Member</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="view-members">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th colspan="2">Status</th>
            </tr>
            <tr v-for="member in savedMembers">
              <td>{{ member.firstName }} {{ member.lastName }}</td>
              <td>{{ member.email }}</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  `,
  data() {
    return {
      search: null,
      firstName: null,
      lastName: null,
      email: null,
      errors: [],
      savedMembers: [],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    addNewTeamMember(newTeamMember) {
      this.savedMembers.push(newTeamMember);
    },
    onSubmit() {
      if (this.firstName && this.lastName && this.email) {
        let newTeamMember = {
          firstName: this.firstName,
          lastName: this.lastName,
          email: this.email,
        };
        this.addNewTeamMember(newTeamMember);
        //this.$emit('members-submitted', newTeamMember)
        this.firstName = null;
        this.lastName = null;
        this.email = null;
      } else {
        if (!this.firstName) this.errors.push("First name required");
        if (!this.lastName) this.errors.push("Last name required");
        if (!this.email) this.errors.push("Email required");
      }
    },
  },
  computed: {
    /*filteredList() {
      return this.savedMembers.filter((member) => {
        return member.firstName
          .toLowerCase()
          .includes(this.search.toLowerCase());
      });
    },*/
  },
});

var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {},
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this part](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Caching-vs-Methods) of the documentation:

*"Computed properties are cached based on their reactive dependencies. A computed property will only re-evaluate when some of its reactive dependencies have changed."*

Which means that, in your case, the `filteredList` would only change if the `this.savedMembers` array change.

So, the correct way would be that:

1. Create another array, let's assume `filteredSavedMembers`
2. You create a method to react whenever the `search` changes ( i.e `<input @change="onSearchChange".../>`
3. In this method, you will assign your filtering to the `filteredSavedMembers`
4. And that's it, now you only have to show your filterd list in the template.

**Obs:* to filter by multiple values, you can use the `or (||)` operator, like this:

```
const search = this.search.toLowerCase()
this.filteredSavedMembers = this.savedMembers
  .filter(({ firstName, lastName, email }) =>
    firstName.toLowerCase().includes(search) ||
    lastName.toLowerCase().includes(search) ||
    email.toLowerCase().includes(search)
  )
```

Comment: This is a really helpful answer. Thank you

Comment: Glad to help, if something yet confuse you, leave a message here.

Comment: When I add @change="onSearchChange" to my search field I want be able to connect field to search variable by v-model="search"

Comment: Du you get notifications about new messages @Felipe Malara or do I need to tag you name?

Comment: Only when tagged, sorry delaying it, but yes you can do both actually in the same input, have the ```v-model``` and the ```@change```. @hereinsweden